# Can I assign a name to a collection of packages for easy removal?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt

When reading build instructions for applications I'm often told to manually install <a list of 40+ packages> with `apt`.

Later, when I don't need the packages anymore I'd like to have given the set of packages a name or tag, at install time, that gives me some sort of context as to why they're installed, and to facilitate easy uninstallation of the lot just by referencing the collection's name.

Is that possible?

Currently I have the impression that I have to manage separate notes on the reason why individual packages are installed.

Comment: Just do an install and remove scripts in `python` or `bash`, feeding off a text file. Should take minutes.

Comment: @Vorac What sort of script are you talking about? Maybe you better write it in an answer, because to me it sounds like the equivalent of separate notes.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to pass some arbitrary option to apt when installing.

e.g.

```
apt -o foo=bar install when
```

..results in this entry within `/var/log/history.log`

```
root@ans4:~# tail -4 /var/log/apt/history.log
Start-Date: 2022-10-27  12:53:12
Commandline: apt -o foo=bar install when
Install: libsigsegv2:amd64 (2.13-1, automatic), when:amd64 (1.1.38-2), m4:amd64 (1.4.18-5, automatic)
End-Date: 2022-10-27  12:53:14
root@ans4:~#
```

So you could start making use of some sort of `-o andreas-reason=needed-for-db` construct.

Be aware you'd need to tune `logrotate` to avoid unwelcome rotation/removals.

```
root@ans4:~# cat /etc/logrotate.d/apt
/var/log/apt/term.log {
  rotate 12
  monthly
  compress
  missingok
  notifempty
}

/var/log/apt/history.log {
  rotate 12
  monthly
  compress
  missingok
  notifempty
}

root@ans4:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

Three files:

```
<packages.txt>
list
of
packages
```

The installation one is ... not asked for in the question and I am too lazy to write it. Furthermore, the code below does not work as I am indeed too lazy to get to an `apt`-based machine. At least illustrates the point.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    

# <remove.sh>: Uninstall all packages lised in ./packages.txt.

while read PACK
do
    sudo apt remove "$PACK"
done < 'packages.txt'

sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
```

---

> Let's say two of the "package collections" intersect, e.g. they both
> want gcc — what happens upon removal of only one of them?

Utter chaos of course. How to safely format `packages.txt` is ... beyond my knowledge.

Idea: have the installation script generate `packages.txt` intelligently enough as to avoid uninstalling `gcc`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Let's say two of the "package collections" intersect, e.g. they both want `gcc` — what happens upon removal of only one of them?

Comment: @Andreas Another question is how you'll **tag** a package when there are two collections that want the same package.  Your tagging and find-packages-for-deletion methods will also have to handle multiple reasons that a package was installed.

Comment: @SottoVoce I'm not sure I follow. What would the point be in tagging an individual package in this use-case? Multiple reasons = multiple collections. One collection name = one tag. If you really wanted you could then create a collection only containing a single package. To me it appears to all sort itself out as long as there's dependency management of the collections.

Comment: @Andreas Your question asked about tags, and apparently you envisioned the tag would be against a "package collection".  I'm not sure what this "collection" would be aside from another (virtual) package.  If it's a virtual package, then the name of that virtual package serves as the reference, and there's no need for a tag, is there?  And the reverse dependency shows the package name that caused a package install.  That leaves tags as something added to the individual packages identifying the reason(s) the packages were installed.  And that leads to my previous comment.

Comment: @SottoVoce Sorry if it wasn't clear in the Q. I use interchangeable terminology (set, collection, tag) in order to resonate with a broad spectrum of readers. Git users might get the idea more quickly by reading "tag", for instance; a user-chosen user-side name used for future reference. It's all the same thing.

Comment: @SottoVoce If a virtual package is easily and readily user-defined then it sounds like a possible solution. Personally I have no experience with them.

Comment: @Andreas it looks like the terminology may have changed.  When I search https://packages.ubuntu.com/ for one of these packages that trigger the installation of other packages, the descriptive word that's shown is *metapackage*.  An example is `default-mysql-client`.  I don't know your familiarity with building and installing your own Debian packages, so I can't advise you on how easy it may be for you.  I still think creating scripts to find a package's reverse dependency info will represent less effort in tracking why it was installed.